# What is the identity.xml for in WSO2 Message Broker?

Tags: wso2

Is there any source where I can read what is the identity.xml for in WSO2 Message Broker ?  And also if you can tell me where to read what is this file for, related to other products like ESB, APIM, etc it would be great.

Something like: in message broker you can use identity.xml to ... then in esb you can use identity.xml to ... and so on

I've read wso2 documentation and all of the content refers to the parameters inside the file but none of them states what is this file for and when to use it.

Any input wil be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: After some more research, I would say this identity.xml file is used mainly to configure the WSO2 Identity server component and also to configure identity features that some products like API manager have to complement their functionalities.  For example, when you deploy the API manager gateway component stand alone, maybe you need to configure the Key Manager subcomponent to manage authorization to access the APIs and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of identity.xml is global to the WSO2 product stack. It is use to specify the configuration of how to identify a user. You can find the related documentation [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB220/Configuring+identity.xml).